# "Out of Memory" error in nokia 5610 while loading MP3 file

Tags: exception, java-me, nokia

i am  developing one j2me application to  play wav & mp3 file.

problems are:

- while try to play mp3 file in my phone (nokia 5610d)  it is making "Out of memory" error.
- while try to play Wav file it is giving "Sounds are not allowed" exception.

few lines of my code is here.

**Code to play Wav file**

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Child.wav");
player = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/x-wav");

player.realize(); player.start();
```

**Code to play MP3 file**

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Child.mp3");<br/>
player = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/mpeg");

player.realize(); player.start();
```

Please let me know what is the problem in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try "audio/wav" instead of "audio/x-wav".

I would also suggest using a FileConnection URL (`Manager.createPlayer("file://localhost/E:/MyFolder/Child.mp3");` for example) as that typically works better than Players created with an InputStream on Series40 phones.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make any difference if you call `player.prefetch();` before `player.start();`? All the examples I have seen previously are done this way.

Also try using the mime type `audio/mp3` instead if `audio/mpeg` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, your code is correct.

I was getting "Sounds not allowed" error because the phone was in silent mode and i was trying to play it. Are u sure tht ur phone is not in silent mode while running your code?

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate source for Nokia Series 40 without throwing an exception (Out of Memory error) by launching directly from the SD mp3 files and other such files to allow the phone is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.microedition.media.Manager;
import javax.microedition.media.MediaException;
import javax.microedition.media.Player;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;
public class pro extends MIDlet {
     public pro() throws IOException, MediaException {

     Player player = Manager.createPlayer("file:///E:/03.mp3");
     player.realize();
     player.start();

     }
  public void startApp() { }
  public void pauseApp() {}
  public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {}
}
```